# Spell checking doesn't work with WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox, spell-checking

I'm trying to enable spell checking in a WPF RichTextBox.
MSDN writes that [System.Windows.Controls.SpellCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx) can be used to enable spell checking for TextBox and RichTextBox controls.

Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work for me:

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" xml:lang="en-US"></RichTextBox>
```

Which is strange, because if I use a plain TextBox, it works perfectly fine (I can see the red lines if I miss-spell something).

Unfortunately, [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185481/wpf-spell-check) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870737/how-to-add-spell-check-in-a-richtextbox) I've found on SO so far mention only to set `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` to `True` and set the `Language` property to one of the supported languages, but I have no idea why does this method not work on my computer in case of built-in RichTextBoxes?

**Update:**

If I write that, the text in the run will be underlined:

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument Language="en">
         <Paragraph>
             <Run>asdfasdf</Run>
         </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

But unfortunately, if I try to enter some other text, it will be ignored. It looks like that the property `Language` is not setted to english on the edited content. I've tried to set even the `Thread's` `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` with no result...

Comment: Can you give me some hint about what environment do you test on? OS version, .NET framework version, etc...

Comment: That not a valid FlowDocument and throws a syntax error for me.  First level elements must drive from Block and Run does not.  Try a valid first level element such as a Paragraph.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've edited my question. The Paragraph part somehow lost after copy-pasting the code to the StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, finally I have figured out the solution for the issue. The problem can be easily seen if you dig into the WPF source: there is an internal class called `TextEditorTyping` which has a method called `DoTextInput` which takes care of inserting user input characters. This method sets the culture property for the inserted range through calling `SetSelectedText` on `TextEditor` (`TextEditor` is another internal class providing text editing services for various controls, such as `RichTextBox`). Here is that part of the `DoTextInput` method:

```
IDisposable disposable = This.Selection.DeclareChangeBlock();
using (disposable)
{
    ITextSelection selection = This.Selection;
    if (!This.AllowOvertype || !This._OvertypeMode)
    {
         flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
         flag = str != "\t";
    }
    ((ITextRange)selection).ApplyTypingHeuristics(flag);
    // SETTING THE CULTURE ->
    This.SetSelectedText(str, InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage);
    ITextPointer textPointer = This.Selection.End.CreatePointer(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    This.Selection.SetCaretToPosition(textPointer, LogicalDirection.Backward, true, true);
    undoCloseAction = UndoCloseAction.Commit;
}
```

So the method is using the `InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage` which corresponds to the current input language in Windows. If you use an input language which is different than English (which is the default value for [FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language.aspx)) then if you edit the text in your RichTextBox, the inserted element in the FlowDocument would have the current input language as its `Language` property. For example, if your input language is Hungarian (`hu-hu`), your FlowDocument would look like this:

```
<FlowDocument>
     <Paragraph>
         <Run xml:lang="hu-hu">asdfasdf</Run>
     </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

[This site](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/problems-spell-check-richtextbox-168975.aspx) describes the same problem.

Fortunately, there is a workaround for that. 
We have already seen the source of the `DoTextInput` method, and there is a using block inside that:

```
IDisposable disposable = This.Selection.DeclareChangeBlock();
using (disposable)
{
    ...
    // SETTING THE CULTURE ->
    This.SetSelectedText(str, InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage);
    ...
}
```

This is a change block which gets disposed at the last line - after it gets disposed, the `TextContainerChanged` event is fired which we can handle by overriding the `OnTextChanged` method of `RichTextBox`:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var changeList = e.Changes.ToList();
    if (changeList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var change in changeList)
        {
            TextPointer start = null;
            TextPointer end = null;
            if (change.AddedLength > 0)
            {
                start = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset);
                end = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset + change.AddedLength);
            }
            else
            {
                int startOffset = Math.Max(change.Offset - change.RemovedLength, 0);
                start = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(startOffset);
                end = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset);
            }

            if (start != null && end != null)
            {
                var range = new TextRange(start, end);
                range.ApplyPropertyValue(FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty, Document.Language);
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
}
```

Here we are resetting the Language of the edited range to the proper value - to `Document.Language`. 
After this workaround, you can use WPF spellchecking - for example, in French:

```
<My:CultureIndependentRichTextBox xml:lang="fr-FR" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
     <FlowDocument>
     </FlowDocument>
</My:CultureIndependentRichTextBox>
```

And it will magically work. :)